# Кривой API запрос python

Tags: python, api

функция дает кривой запрос.
код взят из библиотеки csgo_market_api
Вопрос: Как "склеить" ссылку

```
class CSGOMarket:
    ***https://market.csgo.com/docs-v2***
    def __init__(self, api_key: str, timeout: int = 15):
        self.params = {'key': api_key}
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.url = 'https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/'

def history(self, date_start: Union[str, int], date_end: Union[str, int] = None):
    api_url = self.url + 'history'
    api_params = dict(self.params)
    api_params.update({'date': date_start})
    if date_end:
        api_params.update({'date_end': date_end})
    return api_url, api_params, self.timeout
```

когда вызываю функцию history - она отвечает

```
('https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/history', {'key': '9Z8n5cUPCG5e50h754G91Hyq0xChRvR', 'date': '01-01-2022'}, 15)
```

Есть и похожая функция, но она дает нормальную ссылку.

```
 def buy(self, hash_name: str, price: Union[str, int], custom_id: Union[str, int] = None):
        api_url = self.url + 'buy'
        api_params = dict(self.params)
        api_params.update({'hash_name': hash_name, 'price': price})
        if custom_id:
            api_params.update({'custom_id': custom_id})
        return api_url, api_params, self.timeout
```

ps. Если не сложно дайте ссылки на  хорошие статьи про API \ websocket

Comment: Какой конкретно результат вы ожидаете? И как вы проверяете, что похожая функция «дает нормальную ссылку»?

Comment: @andreymal при вызове функции history через принт мне возвращает кусок ссылки и словарь, а при вызове функции бай - мне возвращает уже ответ от сервера: {'success': False, 'error': 'Not money'}

Comment: Вы уверены, что вы запускаете именно эту функцию buy, а не какую-то другую с таким же названием?

Comment: @andreymal уверен, потому что у меня нету других функций с таким же названием + ответ из документации апи по сайту правильный

Comment: В показанном вами коде нет ничего, что могло бы отправить запрос на сервер. Так что вы явно что-то не договариваете

Comment: @andreymal https://github.com/OliverTrust/csgo_market_api/blob/master/csgo_market_api/csgo_market.py - вот библиотека, которой я пользуюсь. Для примера: импортирую библиотеку, делаю переменную market = CSGOMarket(api='вставляю ключ'), далее вызываю функции history = market.history('DD-MM-YYYY') .

Comment: @andreymal '9Z8n5cUPCG5e50h754GoQ46N0xChRvR' - вот апи ключ что бы сервер отвечал

Comment: Ну да, вы не договорили про декоратор. Функция buy завёрнута в декоратор `@_send_request`, а функция history не завёрнута

Comment: @andreymal Помогло, спасибо огромное, пойду читать что такое декораторы)) Как тут вам поставить плюсик за решение?